# ¿Porque me marca error en jquery validate plugin?

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap, jquery-validate

El `plugin de editable` lo quiero aplicar en la siguiente tabla

```
<!-- TABLA DETALLES PRODUCTOS -->
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="TableProducts" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr class="active">
<td><strong>ID Producto</strong></td>
<td><strong>Nombre Producto</strong></td>
<td><strong>Caracteristicas</strong></td>
<td><strong>Muestras</strong></td>
<td><strong>Cantidad</strong></td>
<td><strong>Precio</strong></td>
<td><strong>Descuento</strong></td>
<td><strong>IVA</strong></td>
<td><strong>Retención IVA</strong></td>
<td><strong>Total</strong></td>
<td><strong></strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- FIN TABLA DETALLES PRODUCTOS -->
```

Al cual le agrego filas mediante una función de `jquery` de la siguiente manera

```
var fila = "<td>" + $.trim(idProduct) + "</td>";
fila += "<tr><td>" + $.trim(response.d.nombreProducto) + "</td>";
fila += '<td onclick="OpenModal(\'' + $.trim(idProduct) + '\', \'' + precio + '\');">XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>';
fila += "<td><center><input type='radio'></center></td>";
fila += "<td><a class='tableccant'>1</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a class='tablecprice'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a class='tablecdescc'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td>IVA</td>";
fila += "<td>RIVA</td>";
fila += "<td>TOTAL</td>";
fila += "<td><a class='text-danger delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td></tr>";
var ElementoHTML = $(fila);
$('#TableProducts').append(ElementoHTML);
```

A las cuales les aplico el plugin de `editable` de la siguiente manera

```
// Sección productos
$("#TableProducts").find(".tableccant").editable();
$("#TableProducts").find(".tablecprice").editable();
$("#TableProducts").find(".tablecdescc").editable();
```

Mi problema radica en que hago uso de dos `plugin` para mi pagina `aspx` en la cual el primer `plugin` es el de `jquery validate` y el segundo es el de `editable con bootstrap` . Mi problema radica cuando voy a editar un campo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `plugin` de editable me funciona bien, de hecho el `jquery validate` también me funciona bien ya que tengo otras secciones en donde lo aplico, el problema es que en la consola de google me arroja el siguiente error, alguien sabe como solucionarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias agregar un [mcve], ya que no se sabe donde este generando el error, sin código no hay mucha posibilidad de encontrar el error

Comment: Eh agregado el código el cual anteriormente me ayudaste a resolver, el error se genera cuando me carga el plugin de `editable`

Comment: Si quitas las líneas que llaman a `.editable()`, también muestra el error?

Comment: No no me muestra el error @Piyin ya que no me carga el plugin de `editable`

Comment: Es decir, si quitas la línea que carga el script del `editable`, funciona bien?

Comment: Funciona bien si marcarme ningun error, pero no me carga el plugin de `editable`, para poder yo editar la columna de la tabla

Comment: Cuál versión del plugin estás utilizando? Si es un enlace de internet, compártelo

Comment: Esta es el plugin que estoy utilizando (https://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/)

Answer (score 1):

Recuerdo que alguna vez a un conocido le pasó algo similar, y el problema era que existían dos elementos con el mismo `id`

Si no es así, sería útil si nos dejaras ver el código para diagnosticarlo mejor

Comment: Tal vez esto encaje mas como un comentario a la pregunta que como una respuesta.

Comment: Yo diría que juega el papel de ambas, pero prefería dejarlo en un sólo lugar. Así, en caso que sí sea la respuesta, puede serle útil a alguien más

Comment: Bueno, el problema es que, dad la información proporcionada por el OP, sin poner nada de código, lo que estas haciendo es adivinar, no es una respuesta muy fiable :)

Comment: Ok, eso tiene sentido. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima

Comment: Déjame editar mi pregunta y pondré mi código donde quiero aplicar ese plugin

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/54335)

Comment: @eferion Sí da una respuesta, pero Pikoh tiene razón al decir que es una respuesta más bien anecdótica. Ya me quedó claro para la próxima

Comment: @Piyin es un mensaje automático que sale al realizar labores de moderación

Comment: Si alguien tiene dos elementos con el mismo id esta respuesta resulta muy útil. Si el problema de la pregunta puede ser causado por esta circunstancia, que yo diría que sí, entonces esta es una respuesta útil incluso aunque no sea eso lo que le sucede al autor de la pregunta. Tanto las preguntas como las respuestas han de tener utilidad más allá del autor original. +1, se ve bien.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que si te envia un error : `cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` es que el probablemente no este encontrando el objeto `$("#id")` que estes aplicando la funcion settings `$("#id").settings()`, proba colocar esto en la consola de chrome o busca el id correcto.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que yo no estoy aplicando la función `settings`, solo quiero cambiar el valor de un `td`, pienso yo que chocan los plugin ya que `jquery validate` esta configurado para trabajar con un `button`de `type=submit`, entonces en mi plugin de `editable`, tiene un `button`de `type=submit`, no sera que por eso choquen y me muestre ese error, o bien que id` puede ser el que busca